# Netezza rows to columns showing duplicates

Tags: sql, transpose, netezza

I am trying to transpose rows to columns.
One row per supplier with their yearly gross margin in columns.

This is the table given:
[image: given.jpg]

```
SELECT 
SupplierName,
CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 THEN Shipping_cost ELSE NULL END SC_2018,
CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 THEN Shipping_cost ELSE NULL END SC_2017,
CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 THEN Shipping_cost ELSE NULL END SC_2016,

CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 THEN Retail_Percent_2018 ELSE NULL END Retail_2018,
CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 THEN Retail_Percent_2017 ELSE NULL END Retail_2017,
CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 THEN Retail_Percent_2016 ELSE NULL END Retail_2016

  FROM
    (
      SELECT 
      SUPL.SUP_NAM AS SupplierName,
      SUPL.SUPL_CST AS Shipping_cost,

        (SELECT SUM(Shipping_Cost) FROM MM_TRX_TABLE S
        WHERE YearID = '2018') AS GRANDTOTAL_2018,

        (SELECT SUM(Shipping_Cost) FROM MM_TRX_TABLE S
        WHERE YearID = '2017')  AS GRANDTOTAL_2017,

         (SELECT SUM(Shipping_Cost) FROM MM_TRX_TABLE S
        WHERE YearID = '2016')  AS GRANDTOTAL_2016,

      SUM(SUPL.Retail_Cost) AS Retail_Total, 

      CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 
      THEN (Retail_Total/GRANDTOTAL_2018) * 100 
      ELSE NULL END AS Retail_Percent_2018,         

      CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 
      THEN (Retail_Total/GRANDTOTAL_2017) * 100 
      ELSE NULL END AS Retail_Percent_2017,         

      CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 
      THEN (Retail_Total/GRANDTOTAL_2016) * 100 
      ELSE NULL END AS Retail_Percent_2016,      

     FROM MM_TRX_TABLE S
      WHERE YEARID IN ('2018', '2017', '2016')

      GROUP BY 
        SupplierName,
        YEARID,
        )DTL
   ORDER BY GrossMargin DESC
```

I'm expecting the table to look like:
[image: expected.jpg]

But I get suppliers repeated in multiple rows.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDWAb.png)

Comment: Could you add the output you get using this query?

Comment: Updated my result Andrew. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll give it a shot.

First of all: you are joining way too much for my taste. Remember that fewer joins generally means less decisions by the optimizer, therefore more robust code. Furthermore it is generally better performing in the first place.

If you disregard the fact that you wish the retail to be expressed as percentages per year it is very simple to solve:

```
Select 
SupplierName,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 THEN Supl_cst ELSE NULL END) SC_2018,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 THEN Supl_cst ELSE NULL END) SC_2017,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 THEN Supl_cst ELSE NULL END) SC_2016,

Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 THEN Retail_cst ELSE NULL END) Retail_2018,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 THEN Retail_cst ELSE NULL END) Retail_2017,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 THEN Retail_cst ELSE NULL END) Retail_2016
FROM MM_TRX_TABLE S
  WHERE YEARID IN (2018,2017,2016)
GROUP BY SupplierName
```

If you want the percentages, just join the totals back onto the first result and do the division inside the sum:

```
Select 
SupplierName,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 THEN Supl_cst ELSE NULL END) SC_2018,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 THEN Supl_cst ELSE NULL END) SC_2017,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 THEN Supl_cst ELSE NULL END) SC_2016,

Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2018 THEN Retail_cst / Retail_total ELSE NULL END) Retail_2018,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2017 THEN Retail_cst / Retail_total ELSE NULL END) Retail_2017,
Sum(CASE WHEN YearID = 2016 THEN Retail_cst / Retail_total ELSE NULL END) Retail_2016
FROM MM_TRX_TABLE S
Join (select 
        YearID, 
        sum(Retail_cst) Retail_total
      Group by YearID
     ) T
Using (YearID)
  WHERE S.YEARID IN (2018,2017,2016)
GROUP BY SupplierName
```